# Special Form of Combination - Formula Verification

Tags: summation, combinations, solution-verification

Giving abc
how many combination that involves a ?

answer is

a

ab

ac

abc

equal to 4

I came up with the following formula but I would like to know of its correctness plus if there is simpler form to write it

Number of combination involving a =   $$\sum^{n}_{r=1} \binom{n}{r}-\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} \binom{n-1}{r}$$

Comment: To $a$ we add any **subset** of $\{b,c\}$. There are $2^2$ subsets of $\{b,c\}$. Now generalize, if we have $n$ letters including $a$, how many sets of letters include $a$? We add to $a$ any subset of the remaining $n-1$ letters.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Combinations*" is a weird word to use for what you are describing. I would describe it like this:

> Find the number of subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ that contain the element $a$.

We know that $\{a,b,c\}$ has $8$ subsets ($2^{|\{a,b,c\}|}$). Exactly half of those subsets must contain $a$ (why?). So we arrive at the same answer of $4$.